# Material UI Stack flexbox full width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, flexbox

How can I make `Item 2` full width without `width:100%` using flexbox?

```js
<Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
  <Stack spacing={2} alignItems="flex-start">
    <Item>Item 1</Item>
    <Item>Item 2</Item>
    <Item>Item 3</Item>
  </Stack>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want Item 2 to grow as much as it can you can do:

```
flex: 1;
```

But you have to make sure that the parent Stack component is

```
display: flex;
```

But specify more in detail how exactly you want Item 2 to be displayed. If you want it to be alone in a single row, or share the same row as the other two items.

Comment: Mui Stack by default has `display:flex` and the direction is `flex-direction:column` so I cannot use `flex:1` to make item 2 full width. see https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/

Comment: If your flex is a column, then inner children can be full width with align-items: stretch;
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/